# Get row number of autofiletred lines in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, row-number, autofilter

I want to get the row number of autofiltered lines.

I used  this code

```
With xlsWkSheet      
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="88684240"
        .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="88684239"            
        Set xlsRangeAutoFilter = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
End With
```

But I have no idea how to use xlsRangeAutoFilter  to get row number of autofiltered (Visible) lines

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Did you try `NumberOfRows = xlsRangeAutoFilter.Rows.Count`?

Comment: Are you asking for the number of Rows?  Or, what the first Row is?  Or an Array of *all* the Row Numbers?

Comment: (Also, the option that Pᴇʜ provided will only work if the filtered rows are contiguous - otherwise you will need run a loop `For Each` Area `In xlsRangeAutoFilter.Areas` and add up the rows in each block)

Comment: @Chronocidal You are right. I posted an answer using Subtotal.

Comment: I don't want Number of rows but row number for each filtered line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WorksheetFunction.Subtotal method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.subtotal) to count the rows that are visible and have data in it (note visible blanks will not be counted):

```
NumberOfRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, xlsWkSheet.Range("A1:A" & xlsWkSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count))
```

or alternatively a more reliable method:

```
xlsWkSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
```

---

*Edit according to comment:*

To output all filtered row numbers you must loop through the areas.

```
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Dim Area As Range
        For Each Area In .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Rows.Areas
            Dim AreaRow As Range
            For Each AreaRow In Area.Rows

                Debug.Print AreaRow.Row 'output each row number in intermediate window

            Next AreaRow
        Next Area
    End With
```